# Artifacts in high res pan sharpened image after calculating NDVI

Tags: python, gdal, resolution, pansharpening

I have high resolution image that is pan-sharpened.
When I visualize the original image vs the pan-sharpened, it seems to be good:

[image]

However, when I calculate NDVI I get artifacts- there are different values for each pixel, but I can still see the "extent of the original pixels" ,as you can see here:

[image]

As it can be seen, NDVI is calculated, but there is kind of artifact which seems to be like the pixels before the pan-sharpened.

I thought maybe it has to do with the pan sharpening method I used.
This is the gdal command I used for pan-sharpening:

```
gdal_pansharpen.py -r bilinear tmp/pan.tiff tmp/img.tiff,band=1 tmp/img.tiff,band=2 tmp/img.tiff,band=3 tmp/img.tiff,band=4 tmp/pansharpened_out.tiff
```

And I also thought maybe it has to do with the way I have calculated NDVI , I have tried to calculate using python code and also the gdal raster calculator on QGIS and got the same result .This is how I calculate using python:

```
airbus_pan=rasterio.open('gs://bucket/folder/spot/pansharpened_spot.tif')

airbus1=airbus_pan.read()

nir_abs=airbus1[3,:,:]
red_abs=airbus1[2,:,:]
ndvi=(nir_abs-red_abs)/(nir_abs+red_abs)
```

I have also checked if all the bands are pan-sharpened- and also the bands separated, specifically the NIR and R seems to be fine.

My goal is to understand what could lead to this "artifact" , I am probably missing something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this caused by mistake of having all the bands on the same spatial resolution of 1.5 meters instead of having the optical in 6m and the pan in 1.5 .
When I fixed it, I haven't gotten the artifacts.